Uivision - Looping through CSV file with multiple delimiters
I would really like some assistance.
I am using uivision rpa to automate some tasks.
I would like to read a csv file that contains, a list a videos, each video contains a headline and transcript, the headline is separated by a pipe “|” as a delimiter from the transcript, and the transcript has paragraphs. Each transcript is delimited by a semi-colon “;”
How would I loop through the files to store the headline in one variable and the transcript in another and go through all the videos incrementally?
I so appreciate your help.
This is what I tried but not getting anywhere.
{
"Name": "Process Video CSV",
"Commands": [
{
"Command": "CSVRead",
"Target": "myvideos.csv",
"Value": ""
},
{
"Command": "executeScript_Sandbox",
"Target": var row = "${csvRead(0)}"; var parts = row.split('|'); return { heading: parts[0], transcript: parts[1] };,
"Value": "videoData"
},
{
"Command": "executeScript_Sandbox",
"Target": var videoData = ${videoData}; var paragraphs = videoData.transcript.split('; '); return { heading: videoData.heading, paragraphs: paragraphs };,
"Value": "videoDetails"
},
{
"Command": "executeScript_Sandbox",
"Target": var videoDetails = ${videoDetails}; alert('Heading: ' + videoDetails.heading); for (var i = 0; i < videoDetails.paragraphs.length; i++) { alert('Paragraph ' + (i + 1) + ': ' + videoDetails.paragraphs[i]); },
"Value": ""
}
]
}
